# How do I remove the resize gripper image from a StatusStrip control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

I need to show a StatusStrip control docked top instead of bottom.

User requirement.  Long story.

How do I get the StatusStrip to display without the dots in the right corner?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set the SizingGrip attribute to false:

```
StatusStrip.SizingGrip = false;
```

Comment: I believe the property can be set at design time as well.  Perhaps labeled as
Show Sizing Grip in the VS IDE.

Comment: !@#! I didn't see that the first 10 times I looked for it.

Comment: Oh, so `StatusStrip.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden` is only there to confuse us all...