# How to remove the 'resize triangle' from StatusStrip in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, appearance, fixed-width, statusstrip

I have a Form with a StatusStrip component docked at the bottom. The form has fixed width and is not resizable. However the StatusStrip has a little 'resize triangle' at the right (6 little dots).

This gives the impression that the window is resizable. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the SizeGripStyle to Hide in the designer
or programatically with:

```
yourForm.SizeGripStyle = Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide
```

Edit: Maybe it's the same as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464590/how-do-i-remove-the-resize-gripper-image-from-a-statusstrip-control-in-c)

Comment: OK, found it. SizingGrip = False

Answer (score 1):

From Stefanos's comment, do this:

```
statusStripObject.SizingGrip = False
```